# How to select the surface and import png image to it?

Tags: python, texturing, scripting, image, subdivision-surface

I have the multiple png images that I want to apply them to a predefined 3d object template.
This can easily be done by choosing the option shown in the image attached and then select the .png file to import.
How can I achieve this using python script?
[image]

Comment: You want to load the image to the `Image Texture` node and connect the node to `BSDF`.

Answer (score 1):

The `Image Texture` node should be connected to the `Principled BSDF`.

[image]

```py
import bpy


def apply_image(object, image):
    '''
    Apply image to the object.
    
    object (bpy.types.Object) - Object to apply image to.
    image (bpy.types.Image) - Image to apply to object.
    '''
    if object.material_slots:
        for slot in object.material_slots:
            if slot.material:
                node_tree = slot.material.node_tree

                for node in node_tree.nodes:
                    if node.type == 'BSDF_PRINCIPLED':
                        if node.inputs['Base Color'].is_linked:
                            image_node = node.inputs['Base Color'].links[0].from_node
                            image_node.image = image
                            

apply_image(bpy.context.object, image=bpy.data.images['Test'])
```

Comment: It worked for one surface, Now how can I define the other surfaces and use this function to apply image to it? And another question is to create a script will open 3d template at start of Blender and then apply images and export(I want to run this processes in batches)

Comment: What do you mean by other surface?

Comment: I got it. but now the main problem is to automate it for bulk images. I have so many images named 1.png, 2.png and so on. Is there anyway to open template file in blender, add images(using their different names), export it over 100 times?

Comment: DM me on discord `Karan#5503`